# How to remove time and memory from 500 internal error - Zend

Tags: regex, zend-framework, preg-match, internal-server-error

Actually 500 internal error is the combination of "Time-Memory-Function-Location".

Now I would like to remove Time and Memory from 500 Internal Error.

**Actual Output:**

```
#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
10.0002365832{main}(  ).../http.php:0
20.05691577072Zend\Mvc\Application->run(  ).../http.php:48
30.06211677272Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(  ).../Application.php:332
40.06211677272Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(  ).../EventManager.php:179
50.06221677912Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(  ).../EventManager.php:322
60.06261682144WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->dispatch(  ).../DispatchListener.php:138
70.06261682144WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->dispatch(  ).../AbstractRestfulController.php:313
80.06261682464Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(  ).../AbstractController.php:106
90.06261682464Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(  ).../EventManager.php:179
100.06281686864WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->onDispatch(  ).../EventManager.php:322
110.07321939200WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->onDispatch(  ).../AbstractController.php:129
120.07321939232WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->processPostData(  ).../AbstractRestfulController.php:429
130.07341945960WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->create(  ).../AbstractController.php:234
140.08922331024Model\Model\UserModel->updateUser(  ).../ManageAccountController.php:50
150.08932331464Model\Mapper\UserMapper->updateUserData(  ).../UserModel.php:560
160.08932332744Application\Database\Connection->execute(  ).../UserMapper.php:475
170.08942332840Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter->query(  ).../Connection.php:77
180.08942244472Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Mysqli\Statement->prepare(  ).../Adapter.php:193
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{main}(  ).../http.php:0
Zend\Mvc\Application->run(  ).../http.php:48
Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(  ).../Application.php:332
Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(  ).../EventManager.php:179
Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(  ).../EventManager.php:322
WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->dispatch(  ).../DispatchListener.php:138
WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->dispatch(  ).../AbstractRestfulController.php:313
Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(  ).../AbstractController.php:106
Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(  ).../EventManager.php:179
WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->onDispatch(  ).../EventManager.php:322
WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->onDispatch(  ).../AbstractController.php:129
WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->processPostData(  ).../AbstractRestfulController.php:429
WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->create(  ).../AbstractController.php:234
Model\Model\UserModel->updateUser(  ).../ManageAccountController.php:50
Model\Mapper\UserMapper->updateUserData(  ).../UserModel.php:560
Application\Database\Connection->execute(  ).../UserMapper.php:475
Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter->query(  ).../Connection.php:77
Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Mysqli\Statement->prepare(  ).../Adapter.php:193
```

I have tried this regular expression. But i didn't get the solution

```
/[\d\.]*([a-zA-Z\.\/\\\->\(\) {}]*:\d*)/g
```

Please help me to get the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match 1 or more digits, then a dot and again 1 or more digits and assert what is on the right is either a pattern `{...}` or 1+ word characters followed by a `\` to make it a bit more specific.

```
^\d+\.\d+(?={[^{}]*}|\w+\\)
```

In the replacement use an empty string.

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+\.\d+` Match 1+ digits, a dot and 1+ digits
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `{[^{}]*}` Match `{` till `}` without matching `{` or `}` in between
  - `|` Or
  - `\w+\\` Match 1+ word chars followed by `\`
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g4rtyL/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/XKZvs)

If you also want to remove the `#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation`, you could make use of the `\G` anchor

```
(?:#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation\R|\G)\d+\.\d+((?:{[^{}]*}|\w+\\).*\R*)
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation\R` Match *#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation* and a unicode newline sequence
  - `|` Or
  - `\G` Assert position at the end of the previous match, which will in this case at the start of the string
- `)` Close group
- `\d+\.\d+` Match 1+ digits, a dot and 1+ digits
- `(` capture **group 1**

  - `(?:{[^{}]*}|\w+\\)`
  - `.*\R*` Match the rest of the line and 0+ unicode newline sequences
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3lJMn8/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/HXqeB)

In the replacement use capture group 1

For example

```
$re = '/(?:#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation\R|\G)\d+\.\d+((?:{[^{}]*}|\w+\\\\).*\R*)/';
$str = "...";
$result = preg_replace($re, '$1', $str);
```

---

For example, using the first pattern:

```
$re = '/^\d+\.\d+(?={[^{}]*}|\w+\\\\)/m';
$str = '#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
10.0002365832{main}(  ).../http.php:0
20.05691577072Zend\\Mvc\\Application->run(  ).../http.php:48
30.06211677272Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(  ).../Application.php:332
40.06211677272Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->triggerListeners(  ).../EventManager.php:179
50.06221677912Zend\\Mvc\\DispatchListener->onDispatch(  ).../EventManager.php:322
60.06261682144WebService\\Controller\\User\\ManageAccountController->dispatch(  ).../DispatchListener.php:138
70.06261682144WebService\\Controller\\User\\ManageAccountController->dispatch(  ).../AbstractRestfulController.php:313
80.06261682464Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(  ).../AbstractController.php:106
90.06261682464Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->triggerListeners(  ).../EventManager.php:179
100.06281686864WebService\\Controller\\User\\ManageAccountController->onDispatch(  ).../EventManager.php:322
110.07321939200WebService\\Controller\\User\\ManageAccountController->onDispatch(  ).../AbstractController.php:129
120.07321939232WebService\\Controller\\User\\ManageAccountController->processPostData(  ).../AbstractRestfulController.php:429
130.07341945960WebService\\Controller\\User\\ManageAccountController->create(  ).../AbstractController.php:234
140.08922331024Model\\Model\\UserModel->updateUser(  ).../ManageAccountController.php:50
150.08932331464Model\\Mapper\\UserMapper->updateUserData(  ).../UserModel.php:560
160.08932332744Application\\Database\\Connection->execute(  ).../UserMapper.php:475
170.08942332840Zend\\Db\\Adapter\\Adapter->query(  ).../Connection.php:77
180.08942244472Zend\\Db\\Adapter\\Driver\\Mysqli\\Statement->prepare(  ).../Adapter.php:193';

$result = preg_replace($re, '', $str);

echo $result;
```

Output

```
#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
{main}(  ).../http.php:0
Zend\Mvc\Application->run(  ).../http.php:48
Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(  ).../Application.php:332
Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(  ).../EventManager.php:179
Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(  ).../EventManager.php:322
WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->dispatch(  ).../DispatchListener.php:138
WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->dispatch(  ).../AbstractRestfulController.php:313
Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(  ).../AbstractController.php:106
Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(  ).../EventManager.php:179
WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->onDispatch(  ).../EventManager.php:322
WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->onDispatch(  ).../AbstractController.php:129
WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->processPostData(  ).../AbstractRestfulController.php:429
WebService\Controller\User\ManageAccountController->create(  ).../AbstractController.php:234
Model\Model\UserModel->updateUser(  ).../ManageAccountController.php:50
Model\Mapper\UserMapper->updateUserData(  ).../UserModel.php:560
Application\Database\Connection->execute(  ).../UserMapper.php:475
Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter->query(  ).../Connection.php:77
Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Mysqli\Statement->prepare(  ).../Adapter.php:193
```

Comment: Thanks alot :) . Problem solved with your solution.